# React/JS - Dynamically render image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use [this set of icons here](https://github.com/spothq/cryptocurrency-icons) in my dynamic table component. My current hack was to drag the entire folder from `npm_modules` into my current directory... this probably isn't good practice, is there a better way to approach this?

but I've got so far, now I'm stuck with this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module './cro.png'
> 104 |     src={require('./cryptocurrency-icons/32/color/'+ (coin.symbol ? coin.symbol : "generic") + '.png')}
```

It's because there might not be an icon for a few of the assets in my table. If that's the case, I'm trying to use the generic icon instead.

```js
if ((typeof datalol !== "undefined") 
&& datalol !== null) {
  const coins = datalol.getCoins.assets;

  for(let i = 0, l = coins.length; i < l; i++) {
    var rows = coins.map((coin: any) => ({
      cells: [
        {
          key: 'icon',
          content: (
            <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <div style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
              <img
                alt="icon"
                style={{ width: 28, height: 28 }}
                src={require('./cryptocurrency-icons/32/color/'+ (coin.symbol ? coin.symbol : "generic") + '.png')}
              />
              </div>
            </span>
          ),
        },
        {
          key: 'name',
          content: (
            <span style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              {coin.name} <p style={{fontSize: 10, paddingLeft: 5}}>[{coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}]</p>
            </span>
          ),
        },
      ],
    }))
  }
}
```

How close am I?

When I do:

```
src={require('./cryptocurrency-icons/32/color/'+ (!coin.symbol ? coin.symbol : "generic") + '.png')}
```

It shows the generic icon for them all.

Comment: there's just no cro.png in https://github.com/spothq/cryptocurrency-icons/tree/master/32/color

Comment: @kinoth for the missing icons im trying to use the generic icon

Comment: There's an error in your logic. Otherwise the error message wont be `Cannot find module './cro.png'`. Require is definately looking for cro.png (because `coin.symbol === true`) which can't be found as its not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GEAfan said, remove `require()` - static assets are usually served from `/public/` folder.

So, I'd create a folder like `/public/assets/` and copy all folders from `./node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/` to `/public/assets/images/` folder. Since then you are able to pass a string to `src` proptery.

Also template literal syntax e.g. using backticks rather then concatinating strings, makes your code more readable

```js
...
<img
  alt="icon"
  style={{ width: 28, height: 28 }}
  src={`/assets/images/32/color/${coin.symbol ? coin.symbol : "generic"}.png`}
/>
```

Since `coin.symbol` is always true you will have to dynamically import assets to test if they are actually there, so that you are able to set the generic icon.

```js
var rows = coins.map((coin: any) => {
    let hasFile: Boolean;
    
    import(`your/path/to/${coin.symbol}.png`).then(() => hasFile = true).catch(() => hasFile = false)
    
  return {
    cells: [
      {
        key: "icon",
        content: (
          <span style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <div style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
              <img
                alt='icon'
                style={{ width: "32px", height: "32px" }}
                src={`/assets/images/black/${hasFile ? coin.symbol + "@2x" : "generic"}.png`}
              />
            </div>
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        key: "name",
        content: (
          <span style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
            {coin.name}{" "}
            <p style={{ fontSize: 10, paddingLeft: 5 }}>[{coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}]</p>
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        key: "price",
        content: <p>${coin.current_price}</p>,
      },
      {
        key: "mcap",
        content: <p>{coin.market_cap}</p>,
      },
      {
        key: "vol",
        content: <p>{coin.total_volume}</p>,
      },
      {
        key: "last24",
        content: <p>+{coin.price_change_24h}</p>,
      },
      {
        key: "action",
        content: <Button>...</Button>,
      },
    ],
  };
});
```

Comment: still appears broken! https://i.imgur.com/Z3WLv7q.png

Comment: what's your folder structure?

Comment: ah, had to fix the filename, still doesn't show the generic icons though! https://i.imgur.com/V7pEG67.png

Comment: .. probably `/assets/images/32/color/${coin.symbol ? coin.symbol + '@2x' : 'generic'}.png`

Comment: well... your `coin.symbol` is always true, so `'generic'` is never gonna get placed. Just look at an image tag in your DOM. I guess OKB is something like `src='/assets/images/black/okb@2x.png'`. So you still need some logic to guarantee `coin.symbol` can be false.

Comment: that's where I'm stuck :/ https://ghostbin.co/paste/xmccs

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want:

```
(!coin.symbol ? coin.symbol : "generic")
```

You want:

```
(coin.symbol ? coin.symbol : "generic")
```

Comment: that throws me the error: Cannot find module './cro.png'!

Comment: Are you using webpack?  If not, delete the `require()`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HoBxyjq.png lol i need to fix the logic somehow

Comment: Remove those `()` wrapping the string

Comment: I know I'm getting cloooser https://i.imgur.com/dVQghWS.png

Comment: Leave the `()` around `(coin.symbol ? coin.symbol : "generic")`